# gnuplot: can a function be plotted with vectors?

Tags: gnuplot

gnuplot will plot a data file with vectors.

I would like to set something like isosamples=40 and
have gradient vectors plotted for a 2D function.

I know I could write a python program to generate
the data file for the vectors but
I would prefer to do the entire operation within gnuplot.

Any advice?

Would this be a worthy improvement to gnuplot if not yet implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vectors style and do the computations in gnuplot using the special filename **++**.

Suppose that I wish to graph a direction field for the differential equation y'=y*sin(x).  I could do this with the following:

```
set xrange[-2:2]
set yrange[-2:2]
set samples 30
set isosamples 30
unset key
f(x,y) = y*sin(x)
lf(x,y) = sqrt(1+f(x,y)**2)
lyf(x,y) = f(x,y)/lf(x,y)
plot '++' u 1:2:(0.1/lf($1,$2)):(0.1*lyf($1,$2)) with vectors
```

[image]

All of my calculations are done in gnuplot.  I compute the direction of the vectors, and scale them to have a length of 0.1, all in the plot command.

I use the special filename '++' which generates a set of points equally spaced over the x and y plot ranges.

See 'help special-filenames' for more details on that.

Comment: So the 4 column vector style has the format `x  y  xdelta  ydelta` and here we have from the differential equation  `ydelta=xdelta*f` and then the Pythagoras' theorem to get `xdelta` (and then the scaling factor is applied).